# Solve the second order linear non-homogeneous difference equations

Tags: recurrence-relations

Consider the following linear difference equation
$$ f_{k} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} f_{k+1} + \frac{1}{2} f_{k-1}, 1\le k \le n-1$$

with $f_0 = f_n = 0$. How do I find the solution? I consider the homogeneous version
$$ f_{k+1} - 2f_k + f_{k-1} = -1$$

and found that the solution is $C_1 + C_2 k$. But I don't know how to find a particular solution to the non-homogeneous equation.

Comment: what happens to $C_3 k^2 \; ?$

Comment: "No guessing needed": https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1680820/362604

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily you can determine that for the homogeneous recurrence equation

$$
f^h_{k+1}-2f^h_k+f^h_{k-1} = 0
$$

the solution is

$$
f^h_k = c_1 + c_2 k
$$

now, a particular solution which should be polynomial, you can propose

$$
f^p_k = c_1 + c_2 k + c_3 k^2
$$

and the coefficient's determination is obtained by substitution in

$$
f^p_{k+1}-2f^p_k+f^p_{k-1} + 1 = 0
$$

obtaining the condition

$$
1+2c_3 = 0\Rightarrow c_3 = -\frac 12
$$

and finally

$$
f_k = f^h_k + f^p_k = c_1 + c_2 k-\frac 12 k^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

Apart from trying what Will Jagy said, you can also note that, for $n=2,3,4,\ldots$, 
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=2}^n\,(n-k+1)\cdot(-1)&=\sum_{k=2}^n\,(n-k+1)\,\left(f_{k}-2\,f_{k-1}+f_{k-2}\right)
\\&=f_n+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\,\big((n-k+1)-2(n-k)+(n-k-1)\big)\,f_k\\
&\phantom{aaaaa}+\big((n-2)-2(n-1)\big)\,f(1)+(n-1)\,f(0)
\\
&=f_n-n\,f(1)+(n-1)\,f(0)\,.
\end{align}$$
Thus, for every $n=0,1,2,\ldots$, 
$$f_n(n)=n\,f(1)-(n-1)\,f(0)-\sum_{k=2}^n\,(n-k+1)=n\,f(1)-(n-1)\,f(0)-\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\,.$$